# How separate stuck input box and submit button from each other in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter, xhtml, twitter-bootstrap

In a funny kind of way, the submit button sticks to the input box. I couldn't understand the reason. I can solve it by giving -(minus) margin etc. However, I'm looking for permanent solution.
I've attached the screenshot from chrome's debug tool.

[image]

I want to align the button to the left below the select box.

If you have difficulties to see the image...

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhJVb.png

```
                        <input class="reservationdates"  type="text" name="date_from"/>
                        <label>Drop-off date</label>
                        <select name="to_time" class="reservationdates">
                            <option value="07:00 am">07:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="07:30 am">07:30 AM</option>
                            <option value="08:00 am">08:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="08:30 am">08:30 AM</option>
                            <option value="09:00 am">09:00  AM</option>
                            <option value="09:30 am">09:30 AM</option>
                            <option value="10:00 am">10:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="10:30 am">10:30 AM</option>
                            <option value="11:00 am">11:000 AM</option>
                            <option value="11:30 am">11:30 AM</option>
                            <option value="12:00 pm">12:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="12:30 pm">12:30 PM</option>
                            <option value="01:00 pm">01:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="01:30 pm">01:30 PM</option>
                            <option value="02:00 pm">02:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="02:30 pm">02:30 PM</option>
                            <option value="03:00 pm">03:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="03:30 pm">03:30 PM</option>
                            <option value="04:00 pm">04:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="04:30 pm">04:30 PM</option>
                            <option value="05:00 pm">05:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="05:30 pm">05:30 PM</option>
                            <option value="06:00 pm">06:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="06:30 pm">06:30 PM</option>
                        </select>


                        <div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                            <input class="span2"  name="date_to" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" readonly>
                            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
                        </div>


                        <input class="span3 btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search For Rates"/>

                    </form>
```

Comment: Post your markup to take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the input fields from your input button into two rows using the  `.control-group` class from the bootstrap. That class adds some margin to the bottom of the div that should unstick your button from your input fields:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MYjzj/

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <input class="reservationdates"  type="text" name="date_from"/>
        <label>Drop-off date</label>
        <select name="to_time" class="reservationdates">
            <option value="07:00 am">07:00 AM</option>
            <option value="07:30 am">07:30 AM</option>
            <option value="08:00 am">08:00 AM</option>
            <option value="08:30 am">08:30 AM</option>
            <option value="09:00 am">09:00  AM</option>
            <option value="09:30 am">09:30 AM</option>
            <option value="10:00 am">10:00 AM</option>
            <option value="10:30 am">10:30 AM</option>
            <option value="11:00 am">11:000 AM</option>
            <option value="11:30 am">11:30 AM</option>
            <option value="12:00 pm">12:00 PM</option>
            <option value="12:30 pm">12:30 PM</option>
            <option value="01:00 pm">01:00 PM</option>
            <option value="01:30 pm">01:30 PM</option>
            <option value="02:00 pm">02:00 PM</option>
            <option value="02:30 pm">02:30 PM</option>
            <option value="03:00 pm">03:00 PM</option>
            <option value="03:30 pm">03:30 PM</option>
            <option value="04:00 pm">04:00 PM</option>
            <option value="04:30 pm">04:30 PM</option>
            <option value="05:00 pm">05:00 PM</option>
            <option value="05:30 pm">05:30 PM</option>
            <option value="06:00 pm">06:00 PM</option>
            <option value="06:30 pm">06:30 PM</option>
        </select>
        <div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
            <input class="span2"  name="date_to" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" readonly /><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="span3 btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search For Rates"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, to separate input box from submit button bootstrap uses 'form-action' class, which adds padding and margin to  with button. So I think your decision with giving margin is correct in some way. Try to put submit button into . But I could be wrong.